# What is the meaning of the phrase "common humanity"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

What is *common humanity* as Dickens uses it?

> “You will excuse me,” said the gentleman contemptuously, “if I am too much in advance of common humanity to trouble myself at all about it. I have passed the night — as indeed I pass the whole of my time now — in spiritual intercourse.”

Comment: Hamed, welcome to ELU. All new users should have read about [How to Ask](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) before asking their first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **[common](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/common)** has many meanings, among them

> 1. belonging to or shared by two or more people ⇒ common property
> 2. belonging to or shared by members of one or more nations or communities; public ⇒ a common culture
> 3. of ordinary standard; average ⇒ common decency
> 4. prevailing; widespread ⇒ common opinion
> 5. widely known or frequently encountered; ordinary ⇒ a common brand of soap
> 6. widely known and notorious ⇒ a common nuisance
> 7. (derogatory) considered by the speaker to be low-class, vulgar, or coarse ⇒ a common accent
> 8. (prenominal) having no special distinction, rank, or status ⇒ the common man

While the phrase as used in the quote appears to suggest meaning 8 (*common humanity* analogous to the phrase *common man*), the context indicates that it is actually being used contemptuously, as in meaning 7.

The speaker holds himself *in advance of common humanity*, that is superior to, or more evolved, having achieved a *spiritual* plane.